# How to change <td> value to its true value

Tags: javascript, html-table, passwords

I have this code wherein the system stores different accounts, there's a "add" button to store customer credentials.. in admin page UI there's a table consist of two columns which is "username" and "password" the content of it was display using , but for password i masked it to display as "**" in UI for the password column.

My problem is that I add an "eye" icon beside every password, wherein when the user click it the true value of the password from the database will show.

I need to use td not input tag can someone help me on this?

This how I masked my password from database to display as asterisk in the UI

```
  $true_password = $row['Password'];
  $mask_password =  str_repeat("*", strlen($true_password));
```

An in UI this is my code

```
 <td><?php echo $row['Password']; ?> 
 <button style="float:right;cursor:pointer;" type="button" id="ShowPass" class="btneye" onclick="  "> 
 <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> 
 </button>
 </td>
```

My problem is that I don't know what javascript code I can use to show the true value of my masked password one the "eye" icon is click.

Thank you

Comment: You could use a [password field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password) instead. Either way you have to pass the `true` value to the client, if you want to display it. Another way is to pass the `true` value by image and not as raw text.

Comment: But I need to avoid to use input tag cause it can see the value in inspect element once edit the type to "text

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted. If you want to display the unmasked value by clicking on the eye it has to be present somewhere. Everything you pass to the client can be seen by the user somehow. Else generate a `png` on the server and pass that `png`.

Comment: But is it possible if I display the input tag as display:none so it will not be visible in the UI? or it can still be seen in the inspect element?

Comment: Yes, everything that is part of the DOM or actually on the client can be seen using the dev tools. If you are afraid of users to change input types, you can be sure that those will also find elements with display none.